# See the number of executors and partitions for a spark job in cloudera manager

Tags: apache-spark, hue, cloudera-manager

How can i see the number of executors and partitions for a spark ingestion job in cloudera manager. I just cant seem to find this information.

I looked under yarn/applications found the job but did not find the information also looked under the log files.

I also looked in hue under the workflows for the specific job  I just couldnt find it maybe im just missing it somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the details in Spark history webUI ex: `www.hostname:18088/history`

Comment: I'll accept the answer but could you just provide a little more explanation or detail that would be great.  At first it was no apparently obvious what you meant. I am really new to all this